# Pie Chart using variables with character names

Tags: r, pie-chart

I'm trying to create some pie charts showing the distribution of companies amongst regions and countries.

I'm getting an error saying 'x' values must be positive, which I think is because I'm trying to plot country names and it needs to be a number?

Any guidance on this would be really helpful

Summary: trying to make a pie chart of investor countries/regions to show their distribution (i.e. how many are in the UK, France, Germany etc)

Data: data

Main variables: investor, country/region

Any help with this code would be great!

Rory

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is a placeholder for the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something on these lines

```r
#demo data
investors <- paste0('investor', 1:100)
countries <- paste0('country', 1:5)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(investors, countries = sample(countries, 100, T))

# pie chart code
library(tidyverse)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = '', y = ..count.. , fill = countries)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_polar('y', start = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>